# Security around save_post hook

Tags: hooks, security, nonce

There are a lot of [examples](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box#Procedural) using the `save_post` hook, that include adding and verifying a nonce, and checking the user has appropriate permissions before you continue.

Is this necessary?

When updating/publishing a post, WP verifies the normal nonce, and checks permissions itself, redirecting to a 403 or 'Are you sure you want to do this?` page if something doesn't check out. As such, the hook won't even be called if a bad request was made, so why would I have to double check these things myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `save_post` hook is called every time someone calls the function `wp_insert_post()`. Plugins do that, unfortunately some themes too, and WordPress itself on several places when …

- someone uses *post per email* or XML RPC
- an auto-draft is created
- the *Quick Draft* feature on the dashboard is used
- a navigation menu item is added
- a revision is created

You really don’t want to handle all those action without your own verification.

Besides that, nonces *should* guarantee that an action cannot be repeated by someone who listens to another person’s network traffic. [In theory](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2013/02/preventing-csrf-attacks.html), nonces prevent that. The default WordPress nonces are not very secure in that regard, because they can be reused. But your users might have installed a plugin that creates real nonces. Do you really want to bypass their extra security measures? Probably not.