# the 'save_post' event triggers when I want to start a new post

Tags: custom-post-types, events

I am trying to add a form for image upload for a custom slideshow for every post. The custom post type is called 'product'. The following snippet creates the new post type.

```
add_action('init','product_register');
function product_register() {
    $args = array('label' => __('Product Manager'),
                  'singular-label' => __('Product'),
                  'public' => true, /*it is open to searches and stuff*/
                  'show_ui' => true, /*true implies that you can display a user interface for this post type in the admin panel*/
                  'capablitity_type' => 'post', /*this will build the read, edit and build capabilities*/
                  'hierarchical' => false, /*this tells you whether a post type is hierarchical*/
                  'has_archive' => true,
                  'supports' =>  array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields','comments'), 
                  'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'Products', 
                                     'with_front' => false));
    register_post_type('products', $args);
}
```

After that, I created the meta box and the first few lines of the function that triggers when the post is saved. The problem lies with the save_files function. Despite the checks that I've put, the function still echos "Checks did not work". I'd like a function that runs only when I save the post, not when I initialize post-new.php.

```
add_action('load-post.php', 'file_uploader_meta');
add_action('load-post-new.php', 'file_uploader_meta');
function file_uploader_meta() {
    add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'setup_file_upload_meta_box');
    add_action('save_post', 'save_files', 10, 2);
}
//the following function creates the meta box
function setup_file_upload_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box('wp_custom_attachment', 'Slideshow Image Upload', 'display_meta_box', 'products', 'side', 'default');
} 
//the following function will display your meta box
function display_meta_box() {
    wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__), 'image_upload_nonce');
?>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p>All images must be jpg or pngs.</p>
        <p class="description">Upload the first slideshow image.</p>
        <input type="file" name="slideshow[]" />
        <p>Enter caption for first image.</p>
        <input type="text" name="first-image-caption" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($object->ID, 'first-image-caption', true); ?>" />
        <p class="description">Upload the second slideshow image.</p>
        <input type="file" name="slideshow[]" />
        <p>Enter caption for second image.</p>
        <input type="text" name="second-image-caption" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($object->ID, 'second-image-caption', true); ?>" />
        <p class="description">Upload the third slideshow image.</p>
        <input type="file" name="slideshow[]"/>
        <p>Enter caption for third image.</p>
        <input type="text" name="third-image-caption" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($object->ID, 'third-image-caption', true); ?>" />
    </form>
<?php
}
function save_files($post_id, $post) {
    //first we prevent it from doing autosaves
    if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE):
        return;
    endif;
    if(defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX):
        return;
    endif;
    //we check to see if the current user has privileges to edit the post
    if(!current_user_can('edit_posts', $post_id)):
        return;
    endif;
    //nonce check and rest of code goes here
        if(!isset($_POST['image_upload_nonce'])||!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['image_upload_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) {
        echo "Checks didn't work";
    }
}
?>
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Had you tried not hooking it to `'load-post-new.php'`? Also please elaborate on your definition of "save". There is _a lot_ of saving goes on in WP, since it's essentially anything that modifies a post.

Comment: Ok I will try that now.

And by save I mean clicking on the 'publish'/'update' button.

Comment: Not hooking it to 'load-post-new.php' makes the whole form disappear. Every tutorial used this hook.

Comment: I meant the _saving_ part, if you don't want it to be firing in that context. Although I am not sure on flow there without completely taking it apart in code.

Comment: Use [nonces](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/154600/73) to prevent such accidents. The new post page creates an auto-draft with `wp_insert_post()`. That’s when your callback is called.

Comment: So I made the echo conditional on the nonce being verified. But the function still echoes the same because its still hooked to 'save_post' and none of the conditions above the nonce condition seem to escape it.

Comment: You are echoing it when the NONCE does **not** verify. That's why it's outputting it. And that is exactly what you want. Just `return` there instead of the `echo`.

Comment: nonce is not verifying because its running when post-new.php loads. I would like it to run ONLY when I click update/save.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your save handler by checking if the POST variable is set. If it isn't, no need to handle the request:

```
function save_files( $post_id, $post ) {
    if( ! isset( $_POST['image_upload_nonce'] ) || ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return;

    // Good to go, handle everything.
}
```

For an explanation on *why* the `save_post` hook is firing, see [my other answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/19539/1685).